# How to make a "switch" to enable or disable the display of the help information on the web pages?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Here is the function I'm thinking of.

I would use the javascript in boostrap to add hover popover as help notice.
The user can choose to display or hide the notice for the whole website.

I plan to override the pages, instead of putting the help info in the pages.

Is there any better way to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest using qTip plug in, you may display help in tooltip window, and then there is a function to disable all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume you have jquery and some float div containing help information

```
<div id='help1' class='float_help">
   Help me :(
</div>

<div id='help2' class='float_help">
   Help me :(
</div>
```

this div may have some css to keep it float and hidden like `position: absolute, display: none`. when you want to show the help inf you may call `$('#help1').show()`
When you want to hide all of them or disable you can call `$('.float_help').hide()` or `.remove()` is that help?

Comment: it is the method i thought of at first. it works, and the help info will be written in the pages. later, i wanted to separate the help info from the pages and use override, but failed. thanks. :)

Comment: if you want to seperate help message into another page, use ajax instead, Load with ajax then append to document body and show it up